# EntityManager and createEntityManagerFactory with application.properties

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, quarkus, entitymanager

I have to create singleton classes using DAO classes.

Following is a DAO reading class example:

```java
package com.luiz.teste.dao;

import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.postgres.ReadSubjectDaoFindException;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.opentracing.Traced;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

@Traced
@ApplicationScoped
public class ReadSubjectDao {
    private static ReadSubjectDao instance = new ReadSubjectDao();
    protected EntityManager em;
    
    public static ReadSubjectDao getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    private ReadSubjectDao() {
        if (em == null) {
            em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgres").createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    public ReadSubject findById(int id) throws ReadSubjectDaoFindException {
        try {    
            return em.find(ReadSubject.class, id);
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new ReadSubjectDaoFindException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is a DAO writing class example:

```java
package com.luiz.teste.dao;

import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoFindException;
import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoPersistException;
import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoMergeException;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.opentracing.Traced;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

@Traced
@ApplicationScoped
public class WriteSubjectDao {
    private static WriteSubjectDao instance = new WriteSubjectDao();
    protected EntityManager em;
    
    public static WriteSubjectDao getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    private WriteSubjectDao() {
        if (em == null) {
            em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql").createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    public WriteSubject findById(int id) throws WriteSubjectDaoFindException {
        try {    
            return em.find(WriteSubject.class, id);
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoFindException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public void persist(WriteSubject writeSubject) throws WriteSubjectDaoPersistException {
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            et.begin();
            em.persist(writeSubject);
            et.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {            
            if (et.isActive())
                et.rollback();
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoPersistException(e);
        }
    }

    public void merge(WriteSubject writeSubject) throws WriteSubjectDaoMergeException {
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            et.begin();
            em.merge(writeSubject);
            et.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (et.isActive())
                et.rollback();
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoMergeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is **application.properties**:

```
# Configuration file
# key = value
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %X{requestID} %s%e%n

mp.metrics.tags=app=${quarkus.application.name},version=${quarkus.application.version}
%test.mp.metrics.tags=app=app-test,version=1.0.0

mp.openapi.filter=com.luiz.teste.dev.ext.filters.OpenApiFilter

quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/api-docs
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api-docs-json
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true

quarkus.http.test-port=8083
quarkus.http.test-ssl-port=8446

quarkus.datasource.jdbc.enable-metrics=true

# Postgre - Build time
quarkus.datasource."postgres".db-kind=db2
quarkus.datasource."postgres".jdbc.url=${POSTGRE_JDBC}
quarkus.datasource."postgres".username=${POSTGRE_USER}
quarkus.datasource."postgres".password=${POSTGRE_PASSWORD}
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".datasource=postgres
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".packages=com.luiz.teste.models.postgres
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".log.jdbc-warnings=false
quarkus.hibernate-orm."postgres".log.sql=true

# MySQL - Build time
quarkus.datasource."mysql".db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource."mysql".jdbc.url=${MYSQL_JDBC}
quarkus.datasource."mysql".username=${MYSQL_USER}
quarkus.datasource."mysql".password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".datasource=mysql
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".packages=com.luiz.teste.models.mysql
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".log.jdbc-warnings=false
quarkus.hibernate-orm."mysql".log.sql=true
```

As far as I've searched through this site (and through https://www.google.com too), I know so far only by using `persistence.xml`.

How to achieve the same result using only the `application.properties` when calling `createEntityManagerFactory`?

**UPDATE (2022-01-03)**: As requested, changed from `@RequestScoped` to `@ApplicationScoped` and changed from *postgre* to *postgres*.

Comment: As a side note: the "short name" of PostgreSQL is Postgre**s** not "Postgre"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the advice. Just put this example to show I want **singleton** instances accessing 2 different databases.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally found a solution to this issue**, after searching lots here and googling for any answer.

Instead of manually creating `instance` field on those classes, to make singleton classes within [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) you shall use `@Singleton` annotation.

Fixed **ReadSubjectDao.java**:

```java
package com.luiz.teste.dao.postgres;

import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.postgres.ReadSubjectDaoFindException;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.opentracing.Traced;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

@Traced
@Singleton
public class ReadSubjectDao {
    @Inject
    @PersistenceUnit("postgres")
    EntityManager em;

    public ReadSubject findById(int id) throws ReadSubjectDaoFindException {
        try {    
            return em.find(ReadSubject.class, id);
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new ReadSubjectDaoFindException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed **WriteSubjectDao.java**:

```java
package com.luiz.teste.dao.mysql;

import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoFindException;
import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoPersistException;
import com.luiz.teste.exceptions.mysql.WriteSubjectDaoMergeException;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.opentracing.Traced;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Traced
@Singleton
public class WriteSubjectDao {
    @Inject
    @PersistenceUnit("mysql")
    EntityManager em;

    public WriteSubject findById(int id) throws WriteSubjectDaoFindException {
        try {    
            return em.find(WriteSubject.class, id);
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoFindException(e);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void persist(WriteSubject writeSubject) throws WriteSubjectDaoPersistException {
        try {
            em.persist(writeSubject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {            
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoPersistException(e);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void merge(WriteSubject writeSubject) throws WriteSubjectDaoMergeException {
        try {
            em.merge(writeSubject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WriteSubjectDaoMergeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The **application.properties** remain unchanged.
To call any of those 2 singleton DAO classes, just use `@Inject` annotation on caller classes, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is extremely weird.

If you want a singleton DAO, just use `@ApplicationScoped` for the scope of your DAO. Don't make it `@RequestScoped` and then have a static instance, it's going to be broken.

Then, with Quarkus, you shouldn't create the `EntityManagerFactory` yourself. You can just inject an `EntityManager` with:

```
@Inject
@PersistenceUnit("postgre")
EntityManager entityManager;
```

and you're done.

Comment: Sure I will follow your advice to change from `@RequestScoped` to `@ApplicationScoped`. About this topic, as I stated, I already tried injecting `EntityManager`, as you put here, but didn't work for **singleton** instances.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to use `@ApplicationScoped` to be able to inject the entity manager given how it's initialized.